# Windows Form sound file does not exist and how to retrieve embedded sound (C++)

Tags: c++, .net, visual-studio-2012, clr

The sound file is located on my project folder and I added the sound file to my Resource Files.
 I don't get any error when I run the debugger within visual studio 2012.

 I get the error when I run the application located in the Debug folder.

However, I don't get any errors when I include the file location directory path.

[image: Sound file not located]

```
namespace FORMv2 {

    //omitted code

private: System::Void Form1_Load(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
             player = gcnew SoundPlayer;
             //no error
             //player->SoundLocation = "c/<path goes here>/soundBit.wav";
             // error
             player->SoundLocation = "soundBit.wav";
             player->PlayLooping();
         }    
private: System::Void checkBoxEnable_CheckedChanged(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
             if (checkBoxEnable->Checked)
             {
                 player->Stop();    
             }
             else
             {
                 player->Play();    
             }           
         }
    };
}
```

Comment: maybe when you run the exe you are switching/loading some other files and the path of the application is changed. so you need to add this, System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location +  "soundBit.wav";

Comment: sorry for commenting late. I was driving home from work. Anyways I added that statement and I didn't get any errors but there was no sound. This is the statement I added (changed the syntax) System::Reflection::Assembly::GetExecutingAssembly()->Location + "soundBit.wav";

Answer (score 1):

I was able to figure it out. 
I found this website:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.startuppath%28v=vs.110%29.aspx 
which gave me the path to where the application is. I moved the .wav file to that path and added the following statement:

```
player->SoundLocation = String::Concat(Application::StartupPath+"/soundBit.wav");
```

Edit:
Found a better way and that was to embed the sound to Form1.resX and 
retrieve the embedded sound. 
I had to changed the name of the file to "$this.soundBit" and add this code:

```
private: System::Void Form1_Load(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
             ComponentResourceManager^  resources = (gcnew ComponentResourceManager(Form1::typeid));
             SoundPlayer^ player;
             Stream^ s = (cli::safe_cast<MemoryStream^ >(resources->GetObject(L"$this.soundBit")));
             player = gcnew SoundPlayer(s);
             player->Play();        
         }
```

and this namespaces:

```
using namespace System::ComponentModel; // For ComponentResourceManager
using namespace System::Media; // For SoundPlayer
using namespace System::IO; // For MemoryStream
```

Answer (score 0):

Include your files in the project`s resources folder by right-clicking on your project name>>properties>>Recources>>select audio>>drag your .wav file.

Then you can play the file from Memory Stream:

```
public void Play()
{
    SoundPlayer player = new SoundPlayer();
    player.Stream = YOUR_PROJECT_NAME.Properties.Resources.YOUR_FILE_NAME;
    player.Play();
}
```

Solution taken from : [Please be sure a sound file exists at the specified location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72439532/please-be-sure-a-sound-file-exists-at-the-specified-location)