# Please be sure a sound file exists at the specified location

Tags: c#, winforms, audio-player

i developed a simple app to play music.

When i run it on debug it works just fine. But after i published it as an application and install it on another machine, it won't run because the file paths is not recognized.

Here is my code:

```
SoundPlayer player = new SoundPlayer();
player.SoundLocation = @"C:\Users\chris\source\repos\Aplikasi Reminder\Aplikasi Reminder\Resources\mixkit-correct-answer-tone-2870.wav";
player.Play();
```

I tried to change the paths into:

```
player.SoundLocation = @"Aplikasi_reminder.Properties.Resources.mixkit-correct-answer-tone-2870.wav";
```

and it won't too..

Please can someone tell me how to fix that, thank you..

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Include your files in the project`s resources folder by right-clicking on *your project name>>properties>>Recources>>select audio>>drag your .wav file*.

Then you can play the file from `Memory Stream`:

```
public void Play()
{
    SoundPlayer player = new SoundPlayer();
    player.Stream = YOUR_PROJECT_NAME.Properties.Resources.YOUR_FILE_NAME;
    player.Play();
}
```